# myname@localhost.com with JAMES

Tags: java, email, mail-server, james

I just installed JAMES (Java Apache Mail Enterprise Server) and I am trying to use this as a mail server.

I am trying to create a mail ID `myname@localhost.com` and I want it to receive a mail from `mail@gmail.com` and save it on to a database.

I already made the connection and I can save it in the database.

My main problem is how to create the mail ID `myname@localhost.com`.

How can I do that ?

Comment: `localhost` is not a domain and so you can't create `www.localhost.com`

Comment: @alpine In an example i saw name@localhost.com

Comment: `localhost` is not accessible on a remote host.
You can only access it locally via `http://localhost`

Comment: @alpine Then how can i test this server as i do not have access to any  mail server ?

Comment: You will require a domain name for a mail server

Comment: perfect using the command telnet localhost 4555 i created a connection and added user using command adduser name password . thanx Alpine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`localhost` is not a domain and so you can't create `www.localhost.com`

`localhost` is not accessible on a remote host. You can only access it locally via `http://localhost`

You will require a domain name for a mail server.

You can create a free domain name for testing purpose as explained in this article

[How to assign a domain name to your home web server](http://lifehacker.com/#!124804/geek-to-live--how-to-assign-a-domain-name-to-your-home-web-server)

Comment: thnx for the info  Alpine  :)

Comment: there is no need to create localhost but atleast can i test it by sending a mail from my gmail account .

Comment: Once you have a domain name for your mail server you can test it by sending email to your mail server from your gmail account.